# using Thinktecture.IdentityModel for CORS . httpContext is null and causes an exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, nuget-package

i have installed the nuget package: "Thinktecture.IdentityModel" in order to open my API for CORS requests. I followed the instructions for opening the web api as given here:

http://brockallen.com/2012/06/28/cors-support-in-webapi-mvc-and-iis-with-thinktecture-identitymodel/

with the only difference of allowing all origins (just to see that it works) and changing the resource name to fit the controller I have. however on any request I get an exception thrown saying that httpContext is null (this is thrown from inside the package code).

what could be the reason?

edit:
if you can't answer, perhaps tell me what other information might help you answer? at this point even wild guesses will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you selfhost your API?
`HttpContext` is only available when hosting in IIS (Express).

Comment: no, using IIS express for development and regular IIS in deployment.